# how to create two observable in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am using `Observable` in angular 2 using `rxjs`.I make a demo of `fromEvent` in plunker
here is my demo
https://plnkr.co/edit/zkgEcdn21CvIKoOycUOy?p=preview

In my demo I take `two` input field .I need use two different observer for two different input field using `keyup` event.
but when I select any  input field it call same function . could I give different `id` to input field .

```
Observable.fromEvent(document,'keyup').subscribe( e => {
      console.log(e.target.value)

    });
```

i am learning from this tutorial
http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/tutorial.html

**Expected out put**

I need to call different function while selecting different input field .will I give different id's ?

Comment: You know this can be achieved with `ngModel` directive right?

Comment: but I want to learn observable that why  i try to use this

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can give your inputs a different id or class and then use them in different observables, however not by using fromEvent. You need to use `Observable.create` instead:

```
var source = Observable.create(function(o) {
  $('body').on('keyup', '#test', function(ev) {

      o.next(ev);
    })
});

var sub = source.subscribe(function(ev) { console.log("test 1 keyup", ev) });



var source = Observable.create(function(o) {
  $('body').on('keyup', '#test2', function(ev) {

      o.next(ev);
    })
});

var sub = source.subscribe(function(ev) { console.log("test t keyup", ev) });
```

Take a look at the changes I made to your [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/n3JKRG6VylvoIgThbCbo?p=preview) to get it working.

Comment: have you used jquery ?

Comment: yeah but you can use document.getElementById instead if you like @user5711656